# Using the 'reductio ad absurdum' to prove the non-existence of two positive integers given a condition

Tags: equivalence-relations, square-numbers

I found this problem in the 'logic' section of my discrete mathematics textbook (I am currently a freshman majoring in Computer Science). It is a demonstration problem and I feel like I might have solved but I would like to know whether or not the procedure is solid.

Basically, it asks to prove using a *reductio ad absurdum* that there are no positive integers *a* and *b* such as: $$a=b^2-a^2$$

I assumed that such *a* and *b* do exist, and the condition $a=b^2-a^2$ is therefore satisfied. I carried $a^2$ to the left side and I got $$a+a^2=b^2$$

Simplifying $$a(1+a)=b^2$$

Then finally $$a=\frac{b^2}{(1+a)}$$

Now, if *a* is even, $\frac{b^2}{(1+a)}$ is even too, being equal. In order to satisfy this:

- if $b^2$ is even, no issues: since *a* is even then *1+a* is odd and the resulting quotient is an even number;
- **BUT** if $b^2$ is odd, *1+a* can't be even because that would mean going outside the integers set(*a* belongs to *N*). The denominator must be an odd number but then the quotient *a* will be an odd number as well (and I guess this is the first condtradiction because *a* **cannot** be *both* even **AND** odd);

Second scenario: if *a* is odd, then $\frac{b^2}{(1+a)}$ is odd too, being equal. In this case:

- if *b^2* is even, *1+a* must be even and since *a* is odd, *a+1* will be even;
- **BUT** if *b^2* is odd, *1+a* must be odd. Another contradiction since both *a* and *a+1* will be odd;

That being said, the demonstration should be done. Feel free to point out any mistakes you might discover.
This is also my first question on Mathematics so I will appreciate feedback on how the question was written and the formatting as well.

Comment: I don't see how your argument works.  You appear deduce that "$a$ even" $\implies $ "$b$ even"....but so what?  That's not a contradiction as far as I can see.

Comment: I expect it is easier to substitute $b=a\times (a+1)$ back in the original equation, then divide by $a$.

Comment: Why not just say that clearly $b\gt a\ge1$ so$$b^2-a^2=(b-a)(b+a)\ge b+a\gt a$$Hence it is absurd that$$a=b^2-a^2\gt a$$

Comment: I also don't understand your line "If $b^2$ is even then $1+a$ must be even".  Why is that true?  It's easy to find even numbers which are divisible by odd numbers.

Comment: You say, "If $b^2$ is even, no issues .."  This isn't good enough.  You have tp find a contradiction in every scenario, not just some of them.

Comment: Too complicated, IMHO.  From $a^2+a=b^2\iff 4a^2+4a+1=4b^2+1\iff (2a+1)^2=(2b)^2+1$ we conclude that $(2b)^2+1$ must be a square.  Now $(2b)^2$ is a square and the only pair of squares that differ by $1$ are $0$ and $1$, hence $b=0$.

Comment: Even more direct than Michael Hoppe, since $a$ and $a+1$ are coprime (any integer divisor of $a$ that also divides $a+1$ must divide $1$), if their product is a square, then each of them must be a square, and the only two squares that differ by $1$ are (see Michael Hoppe's comment for the rest of the argument).